# Are these words indeed uncountable?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I found this big list of uncountable words in English, and I don't understand why they're considered uncountable while I saw many of them countable.

For example:

**Juice**- [List of juices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_juices) in Wikipedia

**Fruit**- fruits in [Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/is-a-tomato-a-fruit-or-a-vegetable)

**Sugar**- [list of sugars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sugars)

and there are a lot more examples against other words in this list.

I'm not sure if this list is wring or maybe I don't understand here something.

[image]

Comment: Note that in your graphic, "cherries" is misspelt, while the glass jug on the right-hand side has no caption at all.

Comment: What is the source of the graphic? Food is possibly the worst category of items to use an examples, as almost every food can be either countable or uncountable depending on context.

Comment: Basically I found the source by googling, not a site or something like that: https://www.thinglink.com/scene/887700493713801217

Answer (score 2):

Substances like sugar, milk, juice ,tea  and coffee, etc  are considered to be non-countable because you can't count them, hence the name. However, in different situations these nouns become countable.

E.g.  I ordered three **coffees**.= you can count the coffee cups.

E.g.   Can you pass the **teas** over here please.= the speaker is referring to three cups of tea which he cant reach.

Sometimes when we talk about different types of **things** (which are normally considered to be non-countable) then we can make them plural (countable).

E.g. There are many types of **cereals** on the shelf.

Often when we place things like juice, coffee ,etc. into containers then we treat them as single self-contained things which can be counted and therefore become plural.

Comment: “Pass the teas over here, please,” would also work if you wanted me to hand you [this box](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/1e/85/49/1e854962a9a44d711ff46e3929c296c3.jpg).